# how to stop the accumulation while using setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var c={{ rest_time }}
var t

function timedCount()
{
    if(c>-1){
        $('#txt').html(c)
        c=c-1
        t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000)    //1000ms后，执行参数1（调用自身）
    }

    else{
        $('#txt').html("time's up")
    }
}
$(document).ready(timedCount())

</script>
```

django view

```
def show_reply_page(request, topic_id):
    t = topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    comments = t.comment_set.filter(deleted=False)
    posts = t.post_set.filter(deleted=False)
    past_time = int(time.time() - t.locktime)
    rest_time = 300 - past_time
    t.save()
    return render_to_response('forum/reply.html', {'conf': conf, 'title': t.title,
                                             'request': request,
                                             'topic': t,
                                             'posts': posts,
                                             'comments': comments,
                                             'past_time': past_time,
                                             'rest_time' : rest_time,
    },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

when I click the button, the django view will give a {{rest_time}} to the javascript. Then it would do the countdown( every second timedCount() calls itself ). But when I click it again, the speed of countdown accumulate. It means when I click it ten times, it counts 10s per second. How to correct this problem?

Comment: Is the ( ; ) semi-colon required at the end of standard js statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

**Option 1:**
Set a global value in the beginning of your function. For example `window.counterStarted`.

But even before you set that value, check if that global value is already set. If so, then don't start it again.

```
if(typeof window.counterStarted !== undefined){
    return false;
}
window.counterStarted = true;
```

**Option 2:**
Define `setTimeout` to a global value like `window.myTimeout` instead of the local variable `t` within the function. Then to clear the previous timeout before the new one starts, use the following in the beginning of your function:

```
if(typeof window.myTimeout !== undefined){
    clearTimeout(window.myTimeout);
}
```